# Making ER Diagram from DBLP XML

Tags: xml, erd

I'm doing some research work on data from **[DBLP XML](http://dblp.dagstuhl.de/xml/)** 
I've Googled if there are any tools or web services that can help me making ER diagram of this huge XML data file, but unfortunately i haven't found any.

Is there any tool that can do this stuff? 
Else how can i read and separate entities of such huge XML file programmatically.

P.S: i'm good at Java Programming.

Answer (score -1):

Hopefully this image will help you:
[image: structure]

Here is DBLP [sample records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/603TB.png) available in `dblp.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="IS0-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE dblp SYSTEM "dblp.dtd">
<dblp>
    <www mdate="2005-10-06" key="persons/Ley93">
        <author>Michael Ley</author>
        <title>DBLP.uni-trier.de: Computer Science Bibliography</title>
        <url>http://dblp.uni-trier.de/</url>
        <year>1993</year>
    </www>
    <inproceedings mdate="2012-09-18" key="persons/Codd74">
        <author>E. F. Codd</author>
        <title>Seven Steps to Rendezvous with the Casual User.</title>
        <month>January</month>
        <year>1974</year>
        <pages>179-200</pages>
        <booktitle>IFIP Working Conference Data Base Management</booktitle>
        <url>db/conf/ds/dbm74.html#Codd74</url>
        <note>IBM Research Report RJ 1333, San Jose, California</note>
        <cdrom>DS/DS1974/P179.pdf</cdrom>
    </inproceedings>
    <article mdate="2002-01-03" key="persons/CoddD74">
        <author>E. F. Codd</author>
        <author>C. J. Date</author>
        <title>Interactive Support for Non-Programmers: The Relational and Network Approaches.</title>
        <journal>IBM Research Report, San Jose, California</journal>
        <volume>RJ1400</volume>
        <month>June</month>
        <year>1974</year>
    </article>
    <incollection mdate="2011-11-25" key="reference/algo/ChenDO8b" publtype="encyclopedia entry">
```

Comment: A picture may paint a thousand words, but a picture of code is less helpful than the words it's painted.

Comment: so you tell me how to upload code file in stackoverflow

Comment: @EdwardIslam - Copy and paste it into the box, highlight it, and click the `{}` button to format it as code.